# JBoss ManagedConnectionPool attributes

Tags: jboss5.x

If I issue the following command against a JBoss 5 server:

```
./twiddle.sh -s myserver:1099 get jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionPool,name=MYPOOL ConnectionCount ConnectionCreatedCount MaxConnectionsInUseCount ConnectionDestroyedCount AvailableConnectionCount InUseConnectionCount MaxSize
```

I get the following output

```
AvailableConnectionCount=100
ConnectionCount=5
ConnectionCreatedCount=38
ConnectionDestroyedCount=33
InUseConnectionCount=0
MaxConnectionsInUseCount=2
MaxSize=100
```

My understanding of these numbers is:

- `AvailableConnectionCount=100` - number of connections available to be 'handed out'. The number of connections that are not currently in use, both created and un-created. How far we are from running out of connections.
- `ConnectionCount` - the number of connections currently created (ConnectionCreatedCount` - ConnectionDestroyedCount)
- `ConnectionCreatedCount` - the number of connections ever created
- `ConnectionDestroyedCount` - the number of connections ever destroyed for whatever reason
- `InUseConnectionCount` - the number of connections currently being used
- `MaxConnectionsInUseCount` - the maximum number of connections ever used at any point in time (ie in this example the machine has been so quiet that it has only ever used one connection at a time)
- `MaxSize=100` - the maximum number of connections in the appropriate `*-ds.xml` file

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's all correct, yes. Do you have reason to believe otherwise?

Comment: No, I just wanted my reasoning to be sanity checked :) Thanks!