# Connection pooling doubts

Tags: java, jboss, connection-pooling

To run my application, I make the war and deploy it in JBoss.
In Jboss, data source is configured having minimum connection pool size as 5.
I want to know couple of things
1) At what point the database connections are made and then pooled? Will they be made when the jboss starts or when i deploy my application war and start jboss or when first request comes in my application.
2) How can i get to know how many connections are being used at a given point of time?

Answer (score 2):

It's described in the [documentation](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigDataSources) (bold mine):

> - `<min-pool-size>` - the minimum number of connections maintained in the pool.  Unless `<prefill>` is true then the **pool will remain empty until first use** at which point the pool will be filled to the `<min-pool-size>`.  When the pool size drops below the `<min-pool-size>` due to idle timeouts the pool will be refilled to the `<min-pool-size>`.  Default is 0.

and:

> - `<prefill>` - whether to attempt to prefill the connection pool to the minimum number of connections.

For connection pool sizing check out: [JBoss ManagedConnectionPool attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519528).

Answer (score 1):

At the time of `Jboss start up` your connection pool will be created